# How to return a Rx Single transaction using Room Db?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

Suppose there is a `Dao` class with the following two methods:

1)

```
delete(items: List<Item>): Completable
```

2)

```
 insert(items: List< Item >): Single<List<Long>>
```

How can I chain them into a `@transaction` method in `Dao` class starting with ‘delete method’ and then returning ‘insert method’ result?

I want to have a method with a signature like this:

```
@Transaction
fun deleteAndInsert(): Single<List<Long> > {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming your main goal is to have the return type of `deleteAndInsert()` as `Single`.

You can achieve that with small modifications

- first by making `delete()` and `insert()` functions synchronous.
- Since `@Transaction` only works synchronously, we need to create another function that calls both `delete()` and `insert()`. Also, annotate this function with `@Transaction`
- Create another new function that creates a `Single` and calls the above function.

---

```
abstract class SampleDao{
    protected abstract fun delete()
    protected abstract fun insert(items: List<Item>) : List<Long>

    @Transaction
    protected open fun deleteAndInsertSync(items: List<Item>): List<Long>{
        delete()
        return insert(items)
    }

    fun deleteAndInsert(items:List<Item>): Single<List<Long>>{
        return Single.create {
            it.onSuccess(deleteAndInsertSync(items))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible.

I once tried it and I got a compile-time error saying:

> "Method annotated with @Transaction must not return deferred/async
>   return type io.reactivex.Single. Since transactions are thread
>   confined and Room cannot guarantee that all queries in the method
>   implementation are performed on the same thread, only synchronous
>   @Transaction implemented methods are allowed. If a transaction is
>   started and a change of thread is done and waited upon then a database
>   deadlock can occur if the additional thread attempts to perform a
>   query. This restriction prevents such situation from occurring."

Answer (score 0):

- Method annotated with @Transaction must not return deferred/async return type io.reactivex.Single. Since transactions are thread confined and Room cannot guarantee that all queries in the method implementation are performed on the same thread, only synchronous @Transaction implemented methods are allowed. If a transaction is started and a change of thread is done and waited upon then a database deadlock can occur if the additional thread attempts to perform a query. This restrictions prevents such situation from occurring.
- When I decompile code to java, I see.

  ```
  public interface CustomerDao {
  @Transaction
  @NotNull
  List deleteAndCreate(@NotNull List var1);

  @Query("DELETE FROM customer")
  @NotNull
  Completable deleteAll();

  @Insert
  @NotNull
  List insertAll(@NotNull List var1);

  @Metadata(
     mv = {1, 1, 15},
     bv = {1, 0, 3},
     k = 3
  )
  public static final class DefaultImpls {
     @Transaction
     @NotNull
     public static List deleteAndCreate(CustomerDao $this, @NotNull List 
       users) 
     {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(users, "users");
        $this.deleteAll();
        return $this.insertAll(users);
     }
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Get Ids of new Data

then delete all items where not in the new data

```
@Query("DELETE FROM product WHERE id NOT IN(:idsNewItems)")
    @Override
    public abstract void deleteOldItems(List<String> idsNewItems)
```

;

Answer (score -1):

If you `delete` and `insert` methods are marked with annotation, they are executing in a transaction. So, basicly you don't need to mark your `deleteAndInsert` method with this annotation. So, than:

```
fun deleteAndInsert(items: List< Item >): Single<List<Long>> {
    return delete().andThan(insert(items))
}
```

Comment: I don't think they will be executed in the same transaction then.