# Room @Transaction and Rx Completable

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

My dao looks like

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(group: Group): Completable

@Query("DELETE FROM groups")
fun deleteAllGroups()
```

I would like to refresh all rows like

```
@Transaction
fun refreshGroups(groups: List<Group>): Completable {
    deleteAllGroups()
    insertAll(groups)
}
```

However, I can't return `Completable` from `Transaction`.
I'm using Rx so I'm expecting some kind of Observable.

Comment: "I can't return Completable from Transaction" -- why not? What is the specific error that you get?

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463342/how-to-return-a-rx-single-transaction-using-room-db?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately, transactions can't be handled async by default.

Comment: Try doing `return deleteAllGroups().andThen(insertAll(groups))`. Or else simply `Completable.fromAction{refreshGroups()}` outside Dao